# Could not load Qt platform plugin "Ubuntu 20.04"

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, pyqt5

I have a python script that I tried to run on my newly installed ubuntu 20.04 but it is giving an error that I could not find any solution for.
I tried entering the debug command ***export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1*** and then I tried to run my script by  ***python3 ImageCompressor.py*** and this is what I got after that(I still don't understand what's the error for) :

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can you please help me out regarding this issue. I am a newbie to Linux and I don't understand anything about this error.
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling PyQt5 package?

Comment: See *Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"* then execute:  `sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0`

Comment: I tried reinstalling PyQt5 Henil, didn't work.  @eyllanesc I will try your answer and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: check this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/114678/problems-with-libqxcb-so/5